# How can I parse this string to get a specific value?

Tags: c#, url-parsing

How can i parse this string

```
https://20.85.239.243:50000/b1s/v1/Orders(26)
```

to get the value 26 in a variable?

Comment: you need to post a minimal reproducible example.  Please a sample of the string and the code

Comment: Have you tried splitting the string on slashes, as a start? Then you can find values between `()`

Comment: What are some other possible values for this string? could you provide more examples

Comment: Don't just provide a single example because there are countless permutations of code that would work on that example but probably wouldn't on other examples you want it to. To write code, you need to know the rules it is supposed to implement. It doesn't seem like you've actually given any thought to those rules. If you had then you could relay them to us, but you could probably have at least made an attempt at the code for yourself too. Spend some time thinking about the logic of the problem, which requires no programming experience, before trying to write code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the string literally like that you can use substring instead.
Maybe like this :

```
string.Substring((string.Length-4), 2)
```

Or maybe you can find what you need here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.substring?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=net-6.0#overloads